# How to get push notifications on updating database

Tags: java, jquery, html, facebook, jsp

I am using Tomcat server, my aim is to get push notifications like facebook on inserting a record in table and I am using JDBC connectivity through JSP for database accesses.

Can anyone tell which way is right to do?

I tried using jQuery of reloading the page by setting time out, but my aim is not like that.

And I searched a lot on server sent events using JSP but I can't find right guidance for it can anyone tell me the good tutorial for it?

I am not interested in achieving it using servlets I prefer only JSP.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to look into using websockets. It's only supported in newer browsers, but there are frameworks that can help with backwards compatibility ([socket.io](http://socket.io/) comes to mind).

Conceptually, you'll need to create a way for clients to open a pipe to subscribe to a live feed. When a new record is inserted, you'll need to broadcast it as an event in your app, and the subscription handler will need to listen for that event and pass the info along to any live clients. Take a look at how [event-driven](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_architecture) architectures work. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13483311/541398) is a fine stackoverflow answer on doing it in Java.