# An example of Event-Driven architecture?

Tags: java

Can someone give me an example of an Event-Driven architecture, a simple one to understand it, i have a project which require a implementation of Event-Driven architecture.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating a simple event driven architecture](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13483048/creating-a-simple-event-driven-architecture)

Comment: Already mentioned that in a duplicated answer, but just in case: a higher-level architecture example: https://medium.com/@wrong.about/service-boundaries-identification-example-in-e-commerce-a2c01a1b8ee9 and here is more lower-level: https://medium.com/@wrong.about/event-driven-architecture-implementation-140c51820845

Answer (score 1):

**The easiest way will probably be to use Swing or other GUI toolkit.**

Swing is implementing the Event Driven Architecture as every interaction with the user is modeled as an event and you have to register an event handler for specific type of event. E.g. `ActionListener` to listen to events that occur when user pressed the button.

Comment: Look at the actual definition please.

Comment: I did, and stand to my (deleted) comment. But judging from the other answers this is going nowhere.

Comment: I understand your complain and it is most likely correct. But I don't think the author is looking for a complicated answer.

Comment: But looking at Swing (or JSF) won't help him

Answer (score 0):

Changing the state of an object is known as an event. The events include a mouse click, mouse movement, clicking a button, selecting a radio checkbox and so on. 
[Here's](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/package-summary.html) all the info and methods you need to know about it. 
For a simple example, here is a AWT (Java's GUI kit) program which uses listeners

```
import java.awt.*;  
import java.awt.event.*;  

class AEvent extends Frame implements ActionListener{  
TextField tf;  
AEvent(){       
    tf=new TextField();  
    tf.setBounds(60,50,170,20);  

    Button b=new Button("click me");  
    b.setBounds(100,120,80,30);  

    b.addActionListener(this);  

    add(b);add(tf);  

    setSize(300,300);  
    setLayout(null);  
    setVisible(true);     
}    
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){  
    tf.setText("Welcome");  
}      
public static void main(String args[]){  
    new AEvent();  
}  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JSF has also an event driven structure.

Controllers (which are handling the users activities) are supposed to communicate through events. This means the Controller posts an event and every other Controller which subscribed to this events will be notified and thus can perform some action.

The following example uses [googleEventBus](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/EventBusExplained) for posting and subscribing to events.

```
// Controller which handles the action if an item is deleted:
public class DeleteItemController {

    @Autowired
    private EventBus eventBus;

    public void deleteShow(MyItem item) {
        // some action here calling a service...
        eventBus.post(new ItemDeletedEvent(show));
    }
}

// controller used to control all items
public class ItemListController {

    @Subscribe
    public void showDeleted(ItemDeletedEvent event) {
        MyItem item = event.getDeletedItem();
        // do some action
    }
}
```